# Angular 4+ Multi Search By Attribute

Tags: angular, search, input, categories, multi-select

I want to implement a search bar in Angular 6 where a user can input multiple search criteria where the keyword could be of the same of different attributes.

For example, photos can have attributes of Place (where was it taken), Date (when it was taken), People (who is in photo), Category (i.e. animals, food, sport). I could search for 1 or more people and the search would ultimately filter all photos that have all people in it. If I then extend the same search to include a place, it would further filter, and so on.. similar to the Photos app on iPhone.

[Mocked Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22men.jpg)

I did find an [Advanced Search Box](http://dnauck.github.io/angular-advanced-searchbox/) but this is AngularJS.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to find such a search bar?

Comment: check this one. https://symrad.github.io/ngx-advanced-searchbox/#/develop

Comment: Great. I will take a look